# Setting the FloatingActionButton ripple

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, floating-action-button

Im trying to set the FloatingActionButton ripple to something similar to [this](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsWDNDYXc2NXJUNDQ/components-buttons-fab_02_xhdpi_002.webm)

From Material design.

The problem is that I only get a "Flat style" where there is no ripple, it just changes the button from, in my case, white to orange without the animation shown in the link above.

I have followed the answer here:

[FloatingActionButton example with Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library)

but my FAB still is boring!

EDIT: 
My current code is:
XML:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/item_activity_fab"
     android:layout_width="64dp"
     android:layout_height="64dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
     android:src="@drawable/watch"
     app:borderWidth="0dp"
     app:elevation="6dp"
     app:fabSize="normal"
     app:layout_anchor="@id/item_activity_title_background"
     app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
     app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
     app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Java:

```
    mAddToWatchListFAB.setRippleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange_6));
```

I tried that method on the FAB but it didn't seem to work. I also tried the steps in the link I provided

Comment: I think this has to do with it being a pre lollipop device im testing it on. I loaded Genymotion and ran marshmellow and the ripple works there. I see something about it not being fully implemented

Comment: ok. I assumed you were using at least marshmallow as you were attempting to use a Ripple which was introduced in that version.

Comment: is there no way by using AppCompat or something to introduce the ripple from greater than 16

Comment: try Search. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760822/how-to-create-ripple-effect-for-pre-lollipop

Answer (score 51):

add following 2 properties to your floating action button xml code

```
 app:rippleColor="@color/textcolor"
 android:clickable="true"
```

making FAB clickable adds ripple color

Comment: Thanks man you saved my hours, that's what i was looking for.

Comment: You should also set the `android:focusable="true"` attribute

Comment: Who would have thought that the button's default clickable attribute would be false?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement it as in the way said my [Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti)

> You can do something like this:
>
> ```
> <Button
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:background="@drawable/ripple"
>
>     />
> ```
>
> Where the ripple.xml is:
>
> ```
> <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>                       android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
>         <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
>             <shape android:shape="oval">
>                 <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
>             </shape>
>         </item>
>  </ripple>
> ```

as said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866786/3073612) which can apply for all ripple needs.

**UPDATE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/item_activity_fab"
     android:layout_width="64dp"
     android:layout_height="64dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
     android:src="@drawable/watch"
     android:background="@drawable/ripple"
     app:borderWidth="0dp"
     app:elevation="6dp"
     app:fabSize="normal"
     app:layout_anchor="@id/item_activity_title_background"
     app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
     app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

And use the above ripple.xml. So simple! All you need to do is to mask :)

**UPDATE 2**

For API 20 and less, There are options to implement ripple effect. Check out the following tips said by [Marcin Orlowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604471/3073612)

Luckily there are few custom implementations already available:

- https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect
- https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple
- https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView
- https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable

including Materlial themed widget sets compatible with older versions of Android:

- https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget

so you can try one of these or google for other "material widgets" or so...

Comment: My current min is 16, this doesnt work as the answer u posted is for 21 min. EG   <item android:id="@android:id/mask"> requires 21

Comment: Updated as you requier @x10sion

Comment: the last link doesnt seem to work? i want to try that one

Comment: The last one is for API 7 or less.. You should try first one

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using transparent, try using:

```
app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
```

where colorAccentLight is a brighter accent of your current accent color. In my case, I used:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#E040FB</color>
<color name="colorAccentLight">#E1BEE7</color>
```

in the **colors.xml** file... Or, you could always set it to some other random color (other than your current accent color) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!--change this to any color-->
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"

    <!-- try this line instead above -->
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ripple colour is transparent. I expect your ripple is showing normally but as it is invisible, you cannot see it.

See this answer for a solution.

[Android: can you have a ripple effect whose default state color is transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308708/android-can-you-have-a-ripple-effect-whose-default-state-color-is-transparent)